# Seeking a note-taking app with geographic mapping features

Tags: note-taking, mapping

I am looking for a note-taking application that includes geographic mapping functionality. I would like to take notes and have the option to associate each note with coordinates or a point on a map. I would like to be able to view a map and see points on the map for any notes with mapping info.

For example, if I was doing biographical research, I would like to be able to take long-form text notes on birthplace and burial location, enter their coordinates, see those points plotted on a map, and be able to click those points and come back to the notes.

**I am not looking for GIS software** or anything that is primarily mapping software. I am looking for note-taking software--like Evernote or Microsoft OneNote--where collecting and using textual information is the main focus, but with a mapping view as well.

So far, all I can find that does maps is GIS with no real note-taking functionality.

I am open to options on Windows, Mac or iOS.